# Need help to convert ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php

What should I write if I have to convert the following code from `ereg_replace` to `preg_replace`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
            {
                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
        }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Change `ereg` to `preg`?

Comment: is the syntax same? because i get this error when I just convert ereg to preg PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Empty regular expression

Comment: Too lazy to read docs, huh?

Comment: please help me out if you can :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter).

```
$row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#", "\\n", $row[$j]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that solved it.